# ¿ Cómo obtener espacio de memoria libre en Android con Java?

Tags: android

Me preguntaba cómo puedo saber que espacio interno y externo (SD) tengo en un teléfono Android. Quiero desarrollar una aplicación que necesita crear carpetas, etc. y que pueda hacerlo en la memoria interna o en la externa. Me refiero a cómo puedo saberlo desde programación en Java para Android, es decir, cómo puedo saber el espacio de almacenamiento interno y externo desde el código en Java de mi aplicación.

He visto que hay algunos teléfonos que también tienen un SD interna.

> Me gustaría saber cómo obtener es espacio libre disponible en todo el
>   dispositivo, es decir, tanto interna (y SD interna) como externa.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: David ya habías realizado esta pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/113275/c%C3%B3mo-saber-espacio-memoria-interna-y-externa-android te invito a leer **[ask]** que  te brindara detalles para realizar una excelente pregunta que sea bien recibida por la comunidad y obtener excelentes  respuestas, modifica tu pregunta en base a el documento que te comparto y yo te ayudo.

Comment: Sí, ya la había hecho, pero al estar cerrada he decidido publicarla de nuevo,  he leído tus recomendaciones y he cambiado un poco la pregunta, sobre todo el título para ser más concreto y claro siguiendo las recomendaciones. Que te parece ?, gracias por la información, la verdad es que hace poco que estoy inscrito y todavía no sé muy bien cómo va todo. Saludos.

Comment: @David tienes algún avance con tu código ?

Comment: @David eres usuario nuevo del sitio, siempre trata de aportar alguna investigación y agregarla a la pregunta, en base a eso puedes conseguir ayuda de varios desarrolladores que se encuentran en el sitio.

Answer (score 4):

Para obtener el espacio libre que tiene el almacenamiento interno o externo en un dispositivo, requiere de obtener las rutas de ambos.

Para obtener la ruta del almacenamiento Externo puedes usar:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
```

Para obtener la ruta del almacenamiento Interno puedes usar:

```
getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()
```

Al obtener estas rutas y mediante la clase [StatFs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StatFs.html), puedes obtener información general sobre el espacio en un sistema de archivos.

Estos serían dos métodos útiles para obtener el espacio libre en Mega Bytes:

#### Espacio disponible de almacenamiento Externo.

```
public static float megabytesAvailableSDCard() {
    StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
    return ((long)stat.getBlockSize() * (long)stat.getAvailableBlocks()) / (1024.f * 1024.f);
}
```

#### Espacio disponible en almacenamiento Interno.

```
public static float megabytesAvailableInternalStorage(Context ctx) {
    StatFs stat = new StatFs(ctx.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath());
    return ((long)stat.getBlockSize() * (long)stat.getAvailableBlocks()) / (1024.f * 1024.f);
}
```

Comment: Nunca esta demás implementar este uso, sobre todo en app que manejen multi-media ...

Comment: Hola, en el caso de la memoria interna sí que me calcula el espacio libre correcto, pero en el caso de la memoria externa no es real. Tengo una tarjeta SD de 32 Gb con 27Gb libres y me dice que tengo libres unos 3Gb. Tengo un Samsung Galaxy A5 versión 2017. No sé que puede pasar

Comment: Acabo de realizar la prueba en mi caso tengo "Available space 3.8 GB", y el método me retorna 3919.414 MB lo cual coincide :| puedes agregar una imagen de donde revisas el espacio, que OS tienes?

Comment: Hola, lo hago dentro de un Fragment en el método que crea la vista, pero lo he probado en el OnCreate(..) y también me da la misma información. Tengo Android 7.0 Nougat, recién actualizado hace unos días.

Comment: Bueno, resumiendo después de hacer unas pruebas, he conseguido encontrar un código que me dice si tengo o no una tarjeta SD física, ya que en el caso por ejemplo de Samsung, cuando intentamos obtener el espacio físico libre con: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(), resulta que nos da el espacio libre creo de la carpeta emulated, con lo cuál, resulta que tanto el espació interno como externo obtenido con el código de Jorgesys, son casi iguales (esto es lo que me estaba pasando), resulta que los dos resultados en mi Samsung solo varian en unas 10 megas.

Comment: Con el código que he encontrado podemos detectar si tenemos una SD física, y según el autor, sirve para Android 2.2+ y está probado en miles de dispositivos, lo que no he encontrado es una explicación del código. Bueno el código es este (autor Jared): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694933/find-an-external-sd-card-location/5695129#5695129

Answer (score 0):

Espero te sirva:

```
    /*************************************************************************************************
Returns size in bytes.

If you need calculate external memory, change this: 
    StatFs statFs = new StatFs(Environment.getRootDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
to this: 
    StatFs statFs = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());        
**************************************************************************************************/
    public long totalMemory()
    {
        StatFs statFs = new StatFs(Environment.getRootDirectory().getAbsolutePath());   
        long   total  = (statFs.getBlockCount() * statFs.getBlockSize());
        return total;
    }

    public long freeMemory()
    {
        StatFs statFs = new StatFs(Environment.getRootDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
        long   free   = (statFs.getAvailableBlocks() * statFs.getBlockSize());
        return free;
    }

    public long busyMemory()
    {
        StatFs statFs = new StatFs(Environment.getRootDirectory().getAbsolutePath());   
        long   total  = (statFs.getBlockCount() * statFs.getBlockSize());
        long   free   = (statFs.getAvailableBlocks() * statFs.getBlockSize());
        long   busy   = total - free;
        return busy;
    }
```

Comment: Es importante agregar una explicación  del código, que método de estos responde a la pregunta del OP?

Answer (score 0):

Investigando sobre el tema, he hecho un pequeño método que muestra el espacio libre en disco en las tres divisiones (interna, externa pública y externa "privada").

```
private void informaEspacioEnDisco ()
{
    StatFs stat = null;
    float megabytes_disponibles = 0;
    String ruta = null;

        ruta = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();//==getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
        stat = new StatFs(ruta);
        megabytes_disponibles = ((long)stat.getBlockSize() * (long)stat.getAvailableBlocks()) / (1024.f * 1024.f);
        Log.d("MIAPP", "MEGABYTES DISPONIBLES EN MEM EXTERNA PÚBLICA /SDCARD/ " + megabytes_disponibles);

        ruta = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getPath()+"/..";
        stat = new StatFs(ruta);
        megabytes_disponibles = ((long)stat.getBlockSize() * (long)stat.getAvailableBlocks()) / (1024.f * 1024.f);
        Log.d("MIAPP", "MEGABYTES DISPONIBLES EN MEM EXTERNA PRIVADA /SCARD/ANDROID/DATA/miAPP " + megabytes_disponibles);

        ruta = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
        stat = new StatFs(ruta);
        megabytes_disponibles = ((long)stat.getBlockSize() * (long)stat.getAvailableBlocks()) / (1024.f * 1024.f);
        Log.d("MIAPP", "MEGABYTES DISPONIBLES EN MEM INTERNA /DATA/DATA/miAPP " + megabytes_disponibles);

}
```

(El método va dentro de una Activity). Curiosamente el resultado es el mismo.

EDITO: Tras tener ocasión de probar con otro dispositivo, sí da datos distintos de memoria libre entre interna y externa. Así que tendrías que preguntar según sea el directorio que quieres usar.